# Cannot read matched of undefined when using router file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So I have a simple router file, that imports different routes for different parts of my website, so:

**general.js** (one of my route files)

```
import Home from '../../components/home/home'

const routes = [{
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    component: Home
}]

export default routes
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import GeneralRoutes from './general'

Vue.use(Router)


const routes = Array.prototype.concat(
    GeneralRoutes
)

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {    
        next({replace: true, name: 'login'})
    }
    next()
})


export default router
```

That is my router, now in my app.js, I simply use it like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from './core/routes/router'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: () => ({
        user: ''
    }),

    Router,
});
```

But this is throwing an error saying the following:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'matched' of undefined"

When I `console.log` the router, I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router` is lowercase

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from './core/routes/router'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        user: ''
    }),
    router: Router
});
```